# Is there a way to search a list in a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am creating a health and nutrition application and I am using unity as my engine. I have a SQLite database which holds the recipes, the fields are ID (primary key), Name, Ingredients and Method. Each recipe is a record in the database and they have their own lists of ingredients. The intent is to allow the user to input ingredients and the program will filter the recipe by ingredients

I expect that when the user inputs flour (as an example) it will show all the recipes that use flour. E.g.: Apple pie, cake and so on. Instead if i want to search the ingredients the input has to be identical to the entire lest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on how relational databases work.  Right now, with everything in one table, your database isn't really any more useful than a simple Excel spreadsheet.

You want three tables; one for ingredients, one for recipes, and one to join them, which I'll call Ingredient_Recipe.  Ingredient_Recipe table will have two foreign keys, one from the ingredients table, one from the recipe table.  Then you can do SQL queries like this example:

```
select Recipes.recipeName
from Recipes
INNER JOIN Ingredient_Recipe ON recipe_ID = Ingredient_Recipe.recipe_ID
Where Ingredient_ID = "oregano"
```

Which should tell you every recipe that contains oregano.

Comment: In my database my tables are setup as such: CREATE TABLE "Ingredient_Recipe" (
 "ID" INTEGER,
 "Recipe_ID" TEXT,
 "Ingredient_ID" INTEGER,
 PRIMARY KEY("ID")
); CREATE TABLE "Ingredients" (
 "Ingredient_ID" INTEGER,
 "Ingredient_Name" TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY("Ingredient_ID")
); CREATE TABLE "Recipe" (
 "Recipe_ID" INTEGER,
 "Recipe_Name" TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY("Recipe_ID")
); // How can this be applied to my database as i am having difficulty understanding yours

Comment: You need to create another table named whatever you want, with it's own primary key, and two foreign keys, "Recipe_ID" and "Ingredient_ID".  Then you need to join on all 3 tables.

Comment: I am using the "Ingredient_Recipe" table in order to join the recipe and ingredients tables

Comment: I don't know specifics about SQLite, but you need to declare Recipe_ID and Ingredient_ID to be foreign keys of the Ingredient_Recipe table.

Answer (score 0):

the classic relational way to do that is to have an ingredients table and a relator table (ingedientrecipe) so that you can query for all the ingredients in a recipe or all recipes that contain a given ingredient

Comment: how would i make it so that one recipe can have many ingredients. Forgive me if this is a novice question working with SQL is very new to me